# Passing custom options to WolframScript file

Tags: scripting, system, version-12

I have an example of [WolframScript](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) file `file.wls` with the following contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

Print["$VersionNumber = ",$VersionNumber];
Print["$ScriptCommandLine = ",$ScriptCommandLine];
If[
    MemberQ[Rest@$ScriptCommandLine,"-h"|"--help"],
    Print["This is help message text."];Quit[0]
];
```

Then I can call it from command line with `> file.wls --option1 --option2` and it prints the contents of `$ScriptCommandLine`, etc. The problem is that in MMA 11.3 with option `-h` it prints my custom help message, but in MMA 12 it doesn't execute the script and just prints default WolframScript help message (also obtained by running `> wolframscript -h`). Other options which don't appear in default list of options work ok (like `--somevalue`).

Is this a bug in WolframScript of MMA 12? Is there any workaround so I can still use common options like `-h` in my scripts? (I am working on Windows 10.)